# Running doctoolchain in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, doctoolchain

I try to configure the new doctoolchain wrapper to run within Bamboo. What I've done so far

1. Create a new project locally and downloading the wrapper `dtcw` and `dtcw.bat` (version 2.0.3)
2. Generate an empty arc42 template `./dtcw downloadTemplate`
3. Create a new build configration in Bamboo using the following configuration

```sh
export http_proxy=http://${bamboo.proxy_host}:${bamboo.proxy_port}
export https_proxy=http://${bamboo.proxy_host}:${bamboo.proxy_port}
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1

echo "Set executable flag for dtcw"
chmod +x dtcw

echo "Generate HTML documentation"
./dtcw --debug generateHTML
```

But unfortunately I receive the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Gradle could not start your build.
>
> Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
> Failed to create parent directory '/project/.gradle' when creating directory '/project/.gradle/6.7.1/fileHashes'

The docker image `rdmueller/doctoolchain` is downloaded successfully and the gradle deamon seems to be started as well

> Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'

My question is now what triggers the error? Is a bug in doctoolchain or is it a wrong configuration?   Btw, locally this configuration is running fine but I don't need to use a proxy like it is required within bamboo.

Comment: could it be that bamboo mounts the docker image read-only?

Comment: It could be possible but I have to contact our support for more configuration details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was that files or directories created outside the container are not accessible inside the container. Therefore, the solution was to max permissions to the working directory.

```
echo "Set executable flag for dtcw"
chmod +x dtcw
chmod -R o+rwx ${bamboo.working.directory}

echo "Generate HTML documentation"
./dtcw --debug generateHTML
```

This allows the user inside the container to access files outside the container.

Comment: glad you found a solution. and this is a good one. Have to write this somehow to the docs!

Comment: and thanx for using docToolchain!